# Describe all extension groups of a given subgroup $H \trianglelefteq$ Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)}$ by Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)}/H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-extensions

Let $\mathbb{F_q}$ be a finite field. Consider the group Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)}$

Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)} := $
$
\
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\colon a, b \in \mathbb{F_q}, a \neq 0
\end{Bmatrix}
$.

Let $H := $
$
\
\begin{Bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&b\\
0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\colon b \in \mathbb{F_q} 
\end{Bmatrix}
$ be a normal subgroup of Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F_q}$ as groups.

How to describe all extension groups of $H$ by Aff$\mathbb{(F_q)}/H$?

Comment: We have $Aff(q)/H\cong \mathbb{F}_q^*$, so that the equivalence classes of extensions are described by $H^2(\mathbb{F}_q^*,\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, every extension
$$
1\rightarrow M\rightarrow E\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1
$$
with $gcd(|M|,|G|)=1$ is split, i.e., $E\cong M\rtimes G$. In other words, we have $H^2(G,M)=1$.

We can apply this here with $G=Aff(q)/H\cong \mathbb{F}_q^*$ of order $q-1$ and $M=H\cong \mathbb{F}_q$ of order $q$, because $gcd(q,q-1)=1$. So there are only  split extensions, i.e., semidirect products.

Comment: Your second ($\mathrm H^2(G, M) = 1$) and last ("there is only *the* split extension"—my emph) sentences seem to be misleading; there can be more than one split extension.  In fact, there is one for every divisor $d$ of $q - 1$, where the image of  $m \in M = \mathbb F_q$ under the action of $g \in G = \mathbb F_q^\times$ is $g^d m$.  (Extensions coming from integers $d$ that don't divide $q - 1$ are isomorphic to those coming from $\mathrm{gcd}(d, q - 1)$.)  Note, for example, that the $d = q - 1$ extension (direct product) is Abelian, and the $d = 1$ one (natural semi-direct product) isn't.